# Python Flask + nginx fcgi - output large response?

Tags: python, http, web, flask

I'm using Python Flask + nginx with FCGI.

On some requests, I have to output large responses. Usually those responses are fetched from a socket. Currently I'm doing the response like this:

```
response = []
while True:
    recv = s.recv(1024)
    if not recv: break
    response.append(recv)
s.close()
response = ''.join(response)

return flask.make_response(response, 200, {
                                           'Content-type': 'binary/octet-stream',
                                           'Content-length': len(response),
                                           'Content-transfer-encoding': 'binary',
                                           })
```

The problem is I actually do not need the data. I also have a way to determine the exact response length to be fetched from the socket. So I need a good way to send the HTTP headers, then start outputing directly from the socket, instead of collecting it in memory and then supplying to nginx (probably by some sort of a stream).

I was unable to find the solution to this seemingly common issue. How would that be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if `response` in `flask.make_response` is an iterable, it will be iterated over to produce the response, and each string is written to the output stream on it's own.

what this means is that you can also return a generator which will yield the output when iterated over. if you know the content length, then you can (and should) pass it as header.

a simple example:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import sys
import time
import flask

@app.route('/')
def generated_response_example():
    n = 20
    def response_generator():
        for i in range(n):
            print >>sys.stderr, i
            yield "%03d\n" % i
            time.sleep(.2)

    print >>sys.stderr, "returning generator..."
    gen = response_generator()

    # the call to flask.make_response is not really needed as it happens imlicitly 
    # if you return a tuple.
    return flask.make_response(gen ,"200 OK", {'Content-length': 4*n})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

if you run this and try it in a browser, you should see a nice incemental count...

(the content type is not set because it seems if i do that my browser waits until the whole content has been streamed before rendering the page. `wget -qO - localhost:5000` doesn't have this problems.